# How to limit the space where Transform.translate widget go through

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

i have the following code which i control of the `Container` movement using `Transform.translate`

```
late Offset offsetLocal=  const Offset(0,0);
 Widget myContainer(){
    return
      Listener(

        onPointerMove:(t){
            offsetLocal+=t.delta;
            setState(() {});
        },

    
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: offsetLocal,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
          )
        ),
      );
  }
```

it work as expected but my problem is that it has ability to be out of my screen scope if i move it there.
in other word i screenshot the following

[image]

How can i prevent this . HELP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to wrap the body of you Scaffold by a widget called SafeArea like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea( child: myContainer())....
```

[The Safe Area widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) tries to keep everything on the screen. I hope this will help

Comment: i have tried this . nothing work